# ¿Como comunico aplicaciones cliente-servidor en C#?

Tags: c#

Tengo el siguiente proyecto que busca organizar y controlar el flujo de atención de una sala de espera.

El ciclo comienza cuando un paciente llega a la institución, saca turno en la aplicación A y ese turno se guarda en el servidor. Desde la aplicación B, puedo ver y trabajar con la información que se genero previamente y llamar a esos turnos a mesa de entrada a traves de  un visualizador que esta en una pc externa.

Mi pregunta es ¿como puedo hacer que esa informacion que estoy manipulando sea enviada directamente a ese visualizador?

Adjunto foto del modelo.

La aplicacion que emite los turnos esta hecha en Windows Forms con C#, al igual que las aplicaciones cliente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Pues hay un montón de formas, pero suena a que lo que necesitas es leer sobre aplicaciones en tiempo real, puedes usar websockets

Comment: ¿No tendría problema por mas que sean aplicaciones de escritorio?

Comment: Pues no, hay paquetes para eso y funciona hasta en consola (https://github.com/sta/websocket-sharp) pero si se te complica mucho lo más fácil es que tu visualizador le solicite al servidor una consulta cada X tiempo y eso sea lo que muestre

Answer (score 0):

Lo mas simple seria usando uan base de datos, ya sea Sql Server o la que mas guste

Si recomendaria es que no conectes las aplicaciones directo a la db, sino que expongas `servicios web WebApi` con `asp.net mvc`, entonces las aplicaciones consumen la funcionalidad que el servicio brinda, asi centralizas la logica de registro y como los clientes toman los datos

La app que genera el ticket o los cliente leen los datos de este servicio, el visualizador tambien

Si necesitas que los clientes que atienden les llegue notificacion usa `SignalR`

[Using SignalR in WinForms and WPF](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Using-SignalR-in-WinForms-f1ec847b)

sino puedes poner un boton para que la persona decida cuando tomar el siguiente, digo pensando que quien atiende es humano y puede que necesite hacer un receso y no quiera tomar el siguiente ticket que le deberia caer de forma automatica

El visualizador si solo va a ver como avanza la atencion si puede implementar `SignalR`, en donde el servidor hace un `push server` enviando la notificacion que hay un ticket nuevo y debe actualizar los datos de la pantalla

Pero en linea general lo que planteas es correcto, solo que el servidor exponga servicio asi puede implementar `SignalR`